# How to call a method from another Form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have my dataGridView in Form1. I have `UpdateForm` method in Form2. I have Click Event in dataGridview Form1 that loads to Form2 `UpdateForm`. But when I Close Form2 after made Update then dataGridview Form1 still shows the old information. I have to reload Form1 to see Changes I made. My question is I want to see Changes I made directly after I Close Form2.

I tried like following:
In Form1

```
Public void RealoadForm()
{
    dataGridView1.Update();
    RealoadForm();
    this.Refresh();
}
```

Then in Form2 update button and tried even in `FormClosed`:

```
 Form1 frm = new Form1();
 frm.RealoadForm();
```

But still not working.

Comment: Read this line again `Form1 frm = **NEW** Form1();`. You're basically creating a _new_ instance of `Form1` and then calling `RealoadForm` which has no effect on the existing form. If you're loading/showing Form2 using a method in Form1, try something like `YourForm2Instance.Show(this);` which will make the current instance of Form1 the owner of the created instance of Form2, then from Form2, you can easily call `this.Owner.RealoadForm();`.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed , thank you for responding. How should I do then?

Comment: I edited my comment to give you some guidance. Just one thing I forgot to mention is that you'd need to cast the owner so you can call the `RealoadForm` method. Something like this should work `(Form1)(this.Owner).RealoadForm();`.

Comment: You can look at delegates and events. Have your refresh form function fire after close button clicked.

Comment: Also, I just noticed this... why are you calling the `RealoadForm` method recursively (from inside the `RealoadForm`)? Note that that will cause a [StackOverflowException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stackoverflowexception).

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I don't know wha tReloadForm() does. I just googled and tried to use it. But now I have deleted ReloadFoprm() and have nothing method in my Form1. So How should look like now without any method in Form1. From1 t oForm2  I use CellClick event by creating object of Form2. like Form2 obj = new Form2(); to load all textBoxex in Form2. Like obj.Textbox1.Text = ........  , obj.TextBox2.Text = .....   then When I click my dataGridview Cell, then I'am on Form2. So How do you mean (Form1)(this.Owner)...? Where to create and how to call it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create public methode that reload your dataGridview. The same method that load information to load to your dataGridview and call it from Form2 like this:

```
 Form1 form = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().FirstOrDefault();
  if(form != null)
  {
     form.YourLoadMethode();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the FormattingApplied = true; in OnCellFormatting event

`OnCellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
     e.FormattingApplied = true;
}`